# How do I add a javascript file from a UserControl to an ASP.NET page only once?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, scriptmanager

I have an ASP.NET UserControl that requires a javascript file. It's a jQuery plugin. I want to add this file only when I use the UserControl on a page. Because it's a jQuery plugin, I need it to be added after the jQuery file is added.

Because of master pages and such, when I use `RegisterClientScriptInclude`, the script is added before the jQuery script and doesn't work.

`RegisterStartupScript` would do the trick, but doesn't seem to work with a javascript file (it does if you provide the actual javascript code).

What's more, I don't want the control to add the script twice if I add it to the page twice.

It seems this must be trivial, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: where do you include the jquery file if a user control? Are you invoking your own js file with doc ready or not?

Comment: jQuery is included by default because we use it extensively in our application. We call the plugin with doc ready, but the plugin itself includes code that needs jQuery. As this uses the default way of writing a jQuery plugin, the code is exectued when it is added (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RegisterStartupScript` can register js files as well.

```
var clientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript;

if(!clientScriptManager.IsStartupScriptRegistered("a_plugin"))
{
    clientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "a_plugin", "<script src=\"/js/a_plugin.js\"></script>");
}
```

Comment: Super, works like a charm although the check on `IsStartupScriptRegistered` isn't necessary because ASP.NET uses the type as a key to see if the script was already registered. Also, you might want to use typeof(), see [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/04/13/registering-scripts-in-asp-net-controls-the-right-way.aspx).

Comment: @Peter:  That is a helpful post on using typeof().  In that same article, it appears to solve the same question posted here by using RegisterClientScriptInclude.  Any thoughts on if this is better than nativehr 's approach of using RegisterStartupScript?

Comment: Hi @DerWolf, I think the startup function renders the script at the end if the form, ensuring that the script is run only when all elements have been instantiated on the page. So that would be my preference if you need to interact with the elements.